# Complying with Schengen 90/180 without leaving Europe (US citizen)

Tags: schengen, europe

One way is to go to UK and stay 91 days.

Bosnia Herzegovina has a 90/180 rule similar to Schengen, but it isn't part of Schengen.  BUT, since the day you cross is counted on both sides, if you go back into Schengen on the 90th day, you'd technically have 91 days in your Schengen 180.  But you can't stay in Bosnia because you would have 91 days there.  So to be legal, you'd have to find some other non-Schengen country to go to for at least one day.

Supposing a US citizen wants to travel on **foot or bicycle** (and if there were no COVID issues), what routes could he use to stay in Europe **legally** without having to hassle with visa paperwork?

Comment: What research have you done? [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schengen_Area) has a map of the Schengen area. Belarus doesn't allow visa-free stays for overland entries, Ukraine and Moldova do. All Balkans countries allow visa-free visits for US citizens.

Comment: Bosnia has no border with any Schengen country.  You can stay in Croatia for a day.  But this question seems to run afoul of the "not a travel agency" rule.

Comment: That said, a more on-topic (and objective) way of asking this question could be to ask about European countries adjacent to the Schengen area that permit stays of longer than 90 days, or about adjacent non-Schengen 90/180 countries (such as Croatia) that in turn have another adjacent country (such as Bosnia and Herzegovina), which could together be used to spend 90 full days outside the Schengen area.

Comment: There are some EU countries which allow longer time based on bilateral treaties with the US, but that would severely constrain your itinerary. They'd have to come last.

Comment: One could get a visa, rather than relying on the visa-free hacks...